# Return absolute number, and percentage together

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, percentage, case-when

I am trying to calculate the total number of [visits] from my hospital database, so that I can use the result to read from my Python script and send out weekly summary to our team every week. So, I am wondering if anyone can help me out for my query since I am still learning SQL.

```
Goal Table format:
 - Date (prefer dd/mm/yyyy)
 - Patient_Name (e.g John)
 - Patient_Id (e.g 12345)
 - Visits 
 - Professionals (Categorical Variables: Nurse, Doctor, Assistant Nurse)
```

So, I want to get a query that can list out total visits by nurse in specific date range and percentage of total visits from all professionals for the specific patient in a week.  For example, Nurse visit patient (John) 15 times, and Assistant Nurse visits 10 times while Doctor pay visits 5 times/week, so my final table would be this:

```
      ____________________________________________
     |____Date_____|__Prof__|__Visits_|___Percen__|
     |06/01/2018   | Nurse  |   15    |   0.5     |
     |02/11/2017   | A-Nurse|   10    |   0.33    |
     |19/04/2016   | Nurse  |    5    |   0.16    |
     |
```

Below is my SQL Statement on my SSMS, and I used case statement for Professionals data since based on patient needs, sometimes therapists visits instead of nurse/doctor so I would like that part to be dynamic:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [myDate], 101), SUM([visits]) AS [Date] , [Professionals], ((SELECT [Visits] from MyHospitalTable)* 100 / (Select SUM([Visits]) From MyHospitalTable)) as Percen
FROM
(SELECT 
   Count(*) as [total],
   [Date] as [myDate],
   [Patient_id] as [myPatient_Id],
   [Patient_Name] as [myPatient_Name],
   [visits] as [visits],
   CASE
          WHEN [Professionals] LIKE '%Nurse%' THEN 'Nurse'
          WHEN [Professionals] LIKE '%Therapist%' THEN 'Therapy'
          else 'Unknown'
          END AS [Professionals]
   FROM [MyHospitalTable]
 ) a
GROUP BY [myDate]
```

I understand that my query is not correct, and need improvement, and if anyone can please help me out getting the data, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe the undesired results or any errors with current query. Queries are correct if they return *your* desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can  calculate the grand total using window function and find the percentage.

Below give you an idea how to do that. it is not exactly compatible with your table though.

```
;with ct as (
    select MyDate, sum(Visits) Visits
      , count(Visits) over (partition by MyDate order by MyDate) TotalVisits
    from HospitalTable
    group by MyDate
)
select MyDate, Visits, (Visits * 100 / TotalVisits)
from ct
```